# TypoScript: How can I access header or bodytext of a record within a split?

Tags: split, typo3, typoscript

I need to render records from styles.content.get from a specific colPos.

the records are provided by temp.recordcontent

The records should be seperated. Therefore I use split.

My Problem ist that I want to seperate the header and bodytext of a single record.

my Typoscript:

```
temp.generateSlider = COA
temp.generateSlider {
  10 < temp.recordcontent
  stdWrap.split {
    token = ###SPLITTER###
    cObjNum = |*| 1 || 2 |*|
    1 = COA
    1 {
      5 = [something]

      10 = [header of the current record]

      15 = [something]

      20 = [bodytext of the current record]

      25 = [something] 

    }
    2 = COA
    2 {
      5 = [something else]

      10 = [header of the current record]

      15 = [something else]

      20 = [bodytext of the current record]

      25 = [something else]

    }
  }
}
```

when I add code below I will get the whole record, but how can I get only the header (or bodytext) ?

```
10 = TEXT
10.data = current:1
```

I tried things like below but this will not work

```
10.field = header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by render the elements within the RECORD Object (temp.recordcontent) and wrap them within the split.

record

```
temp.recordcontent = RECORD
temp.recordcontent{
  tables = tt_content
  dontCheckPid = 1
  source.cObject < temp.getuids
  conf.tt_content.stdWrap.wrap = |###SPLITTER###  
  conf.tt_content = COA
  conf.tt_content {    
    20 = TEXT
    20.field = header
    20.wrap = <h2 class="blue"> | </h2>  
    30 = TEXT
    30.field = bodytext
    30.wrap = <p>|</p>

  }

}
```

split

```
temp.generateRibbonrow = COA
temp.generateRibbonrow {
  10 < temp.recordcontent
  stdWrap.split {
    token = ###SPLITTER###
    cObjNum = |*| 1 || 2 |*| 3

    1 = COA
    1 {
      10 = TEXT
      10.value =  <div class="myclass">

      20 = TEXT
      20.data = current:1

    }

    2 .....

    3 = COA
    3{     
      10 = TEXT
      10{
        if.isTrue.prioriCalc=1
        if.isTrue.cObject=TEXT
        if.isTrue.cObject.insertData=1
        if.isTrue.cObject.value={register:SPLIT_COUNT}%2
        value(
        <div class="ym-g50"><div class="ym-gbox"></div></div>
        </div>
        )
      }
   }
}
  }
```

now I can get the records of a specific colPos and can render every element in its own tiny little ribbon boxes :)